# Retrieve count based on a combination of values from a single table

Tags: sql-server

Wanted to retrieve count based on a combination of values. Sample table layout is as follows:

[image: sample table]

Wanted to know how to generate a report in below format:

[image: Out report]

Comment: Always best to post sample data and desired results as text.

Comment: Here's a guide how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we should show Only those that have the fruit, we could go through a pivot table.

```
declare @table table ( Person varchar(50), fruit varchar(20), num int );

insert into @table values ( 'person01', 'Apple', 1);
insert into @table values ( 'person01', 'Banana', 1);
insert into @table values ( 'person01', 'Orange',1);
insert into @table values ( 'person02', 'Apple',1);
insert into @table values ( 'person02', 'Banana',1);
insert into @table values ( 'person03', 'Orange',1);
insert into @table values ( 'person03', 'Pear',1);
insert into @table values ( 'person03', 'Apple',1);
insert into @table values ( 'person03', 'Banana',1);
insert into @table values ( 'person05', 'Pear',1);

--select fruit, count(*) from @table group by fruit

declare @pivot table (Person varchar(50),Apple int, Banana int, Orange int, Pear int )

insert into @pivot
select *
from (
        select Person, fruit, num
        from @table
) src
PIVOT
(
    sum(num)
    for fruit in ([Apple],[Banana],[Orange],[Pear])
) piv

-- select * from @pivot

select 1 as '#', 'Only Apple' as Fruit, count(*) as 'Count of people who like it' from @pivot where Apple=1 and Banana is null and Orange is null and Pear is null
union
select 2 as '#', 'Only Pear' as Fruit, count(*)  as 'Count of people who like it' from @pivot where Apple is null and Banana is null and Orange is null and Pear = 1
union
select 3 as '#', 'Orange & Banana Only' as Fruit, count(*) as 'Count of people who like it' from @pivot where Apple is null and Banana = 1 and Orange = 1 and Pear is null
union
select 4 as '#', 'Apple, Orange & Banana Only' as Fruit, count(*) as 'Count of people who like it' from @pivot where Apple = 1 and Banana = 1 and Orange = 1 and Pear is null
```

*this is done on a sql server*

After making the Pivot, it is straight forward to find the individual fruit selections.

The Pivot table looks like this:

[image]

And the final result is:

[image]

Comment: That wrong twice, first OP doesn't want to group by name of person, just fruit. Second OP wants to consider groups of fruit as well.

Comment: Yes, Need is to get the count based on the fruit i.e. only one fruit or a combination of fruits

Comment: Thank you for your response. Wanted to know if it is possible to get the count exclusive for the fruit in criteria, i.e. for Pear it should only return 1 (which is person 5 and should not include person03 as he has other fruits assigned)

Comment: ahh ok, so the first 2 is only if the person have one fruit (apple or pear)?

Comment: Right, that is where i had challenge with so trying to get some help resolve it.

Comment: Thank you Frank, it worked exactly as i needed. Appreciate your help.